# Preload Springboot application with data

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and I need it to populate `users` table with an admin account during database initialization as root account.

Checking around the web, I am told to make sure I have this in my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.generate-ddl= true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I also have `data.sql` in `resourses` folder with following SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('admin', '$shiro1$SHA-256$500000$FkZcH5hP9oiYkP6UBK/84Q==$RHFwVRYTKNnCpKtlOu3Nfts8I+3Azfw5iUWokmW0dgI=')
```

When I run the app, this data is not inserted into the users table

## Update

I have [this Github repo](https://github.com/yunus89/spring-boot-javafx-jpa-shiro-demo.git) for demonstration.

Comment: Why do you have leading spaces the property values? I don't think it might be a problem, but I would try `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a `schema.sql` file too, and it cannot be empty; it is a hack but you can create a `schema.sql` with the following content:

```
SELECT 1;
```

And everything should work correctly.

Refer to the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) for more details.

Comment: Hi, when i added schema.sql, data is inserted. The problem is it keep on inserting again and again everytime i run the app

Comment: That's generally what it's supposed to do - there's no way for Spring to know if it has been executed before or not. That's what the migration tools like Liquibase are for

Comment: Try using 'on duplicate key ignore' in your inserts.